# Regular Expression with or condition

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement in which the result screen displayed the name in (), []. For example:

```
(son of X) (Smith),(son of X) Smith
[Son of X] Smith
[Son of X] [Smith]
```

I want to retrieve the first name in it .  I tried the below regular expression for the first string but it does not help:

```
        String name="(son of x) (Smith)";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\(.*\\)\\b").matcher(name);
        while (matcher.find() ) {
              System.out.println(matcher.group() );
         }
```

Can somebody help in forming the regular expression ? Also please let how to give a or condition?

Comment: Search for "either X or Y" in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: What is the exact output you want?

Comment: Try [`"^[(\\[].*?[)\\]]\\W*(\\w+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/PrFogN/1) regex and grab the value in Group 1 (`matcher.group(1)`).

Comment: I want the first word: (son of X), [son of X] in it.

Comment: Then use [`"^[(\\[](.*?)[)\\]]"`](https://regex101.com/r/PrFogN/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to anchor the search at the start of the string with `^`, then match either `(` or `[`, then *capture* 0+ chars other, up to the first `)` or `]`.

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/XkgvPK):

```
//String s = "(son of X) (Smith),(son of X) Smith"; // son of X
String s = "[Son of X] Smith"; // Son of X
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[(\\[](.*?)[\\])]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[(\\[]` - a `[` or `(`
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first
- `[\\])]` - a `)` or `]`.